# [Objective-C]AppDelegateにて、UIAlertControllerを表示させる方法

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

今までUIAlertViewを使用していたのですが、
これをUIAlertControllerに一律置き換えています。

そこで、AppDelegate上にあるAlertViewを
どのように置き換えるかという点について教えてください。
（ViewControllerではないので、presentViewControllerができずにいます）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以前qiitaへ投稿した記事からの抜粋です。
http://qiita.com/takabosoft/items/162b6d90e00b79a7e328

どこから呼び出しても（各種モーダルビューが出ていても）大丈夫なように作ったつもりです。

```
// 警告を表示します。OKボタンタップで閉じます。
void Warning(NSString *message) {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];

    // 親ビューコンをなんとか検索
    UIViewController *baseView = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
while (baseView.presentedViewController != nil && !baseView.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed) {
    baseView = baseView.presentedViewController;
    }
    [baseView presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ご参考まで。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
こちらで無事に解決する事ができました！
助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

AppDelegateクラスは、テンプレートから変更していなければ、`window`というプロパティがあります。それを前提にし、Alert Controllerのインスタンス名を`alertController`とすると、

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: alertController animated: YES completion: NULL];
```

ただし、`self.window.rootViewController`が、現在画面に表示されているView Controllerでないかもしれないので、そこは注意が必要でしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
こちらで取得する事ができました。
ただ、やはり現状の画面と一致しておらず、取得する為の仕組みを考えてました。
今回はこれで解決ができませんでしたが、今回の用途でなければ、これで大丈夫かも知れません。